# Move value to end of queue in C

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I'm fairly new to C and I'm trying to use this function to move a value to the end of a queue. It works the first two times, but the third time something goes wrong regarding the while loop and I'm not sure what's causing it. Any help at all would be appreciated. :)

```
void enqueue(queue q, int value)
{
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Create new node
    node * newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Add node to end of queue
    newNode->value = value;

    if (q->head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = q->head;
        q->head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        node * head = q->head;

        while (head->next != NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
        }

        // Update queue pointer
        head->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: code seems fine, may be there is problem in some other part of code

Comment: try making sure that every time you create a new Node, its next pointer is null.
So add at this line "newNode->next = NULL" right after "newNode->value = value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `q->head` is non-NULL, you never set `newNode->next`, leaving it uninitialised.  The next code to walk the list will follow this uninitialised pointer, leading to undefined behaviour and probably a crash.

To fix this, you just need to initialise `newNode->next`

```
newNode->value = value;
newNode->next = NULL;
if (q->head == NULL)
{
    q->head = newNode;
}
else
    /* your code as before */
```